# ¿Cómo obtener cobertura de código en go que incluya cobertura de expresiones (ramas) y posibilidad de ignorar líneas?

Tags: go, pruebas-unitarias, cobertura

Existe istanbul (nyc) en JavaScript que calcula la cobertura de código, diferenciando la cobertura en líneas, branches (expresiones) y llamadas a función, además de poder agregar comentarios en el códgio para ignorar líneas y bloques.

**Necesito saber si existe un herramienta que haga lo mismo en Go.**

Probé con `go test -coverage` (solo cubre líneas) `gobco` (solo cubre branches y nada más); además en ninguno de ellos se pueden marcar líneas ignoradas.

También intenté `courtney` pero no funciona tamoco.